# Howto grab something from a database table being used in a Table on a HTML sheet

Tags: php, html, sqlite

So, I have a database full of information, essentially what I want is I have a table with a list of Bands, they have things like contact info, home cities and whom to contact.I want to turn the page table entries into links that link to a html page that get loaded with that database entry's full information. I know this sounds weird, I'm having trouble describing it too. But I have a coverpage that has a table with bands, it states their name,contact info and homecity. I want to turn the table entries of the bands into links that link to a NEW page that store all the database information on them. For example the database has a more details like genres, descriptions, band members etc.

```
<?php
  //echo("Hello Retrieving Table");
  $bandquery = "SELECT Bands.Name,Bands.City,Bands.Contact,Bands.Primary_Genre FROM Bands";
  //echo("Trimming Query");
  trim($bandquery);
  //echo("Stripping Slashes");
  $bandquery = stripslashes($bandquery);
  //echo("Setting up Query");

  $results = $db->query($bandquery);
  if (!$results){
    echo("<h2>Error: The query could not be executed.</h2>");
    $error = $db->lastErrorMsg();
    echo("<p>$error<p>");
    exit;
  }

  echo("<table><tr>");
  for($i=0;$i<$num_cols;$i++){
    $head = $results->columnName($i);
    echo("<th>$head</th>");
  }
  echo ("</tr>");
  // Write rows into table
  while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    echo ("<tr>");
    foreach($row as $v){ //I want id of the link to be the band id which Idk how to grab those and use this.
      echo ("<td><a href="band_detail.php?id=$v">"$v </a></td>");
    }
    echo ("</tr>");
  }
  echo ("</table>");
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a tabular **overview** of bands, and then multiple **individual** pages representing each band. That's actually not as hard as it sounds. You're already passing through the ID into the `a href` - now all you need to do is set up `band_detail.php` to use this ID through `$id = $_GET['id']`. Simply pass that `id` into a parameterised query (like `SELECT * FROM bands WHERE id = ?`) to retrieve the individual band's information. Also, you need to use **single** quotes for your `a href`; you have a syntax error there as it stands :)

Comment: I have a small problem it's directing the link as link?=ARRAY i set it to $row hoping like row 1 would mean it'd be ?=1

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SQLite3, but it sounds like you have an array within an array. You might need something like `foreach($row->item as $v)`.

Comment: My Table doesn't show if I use that foreach